# Need A Modulus Formula In Php

Tags: php, math, formula

I am creating a fee calculator and fee is calculated on based of capital. So I want a formula in php.

if capital is <=1000000 then fee is 1000
if capital is 1100000 - 2000000 fee is 2000
if capital is 2100000 - 3000000 fee is 3000
if capital is 3100000 - 4000000 fee is 4000
if capital is 4100000 - 5000000 fee is 5000
and so on 
so what i want is i want a formula that will give me a fee of 1000 per 10 Lakh

Comment: ok, what have you tried? where's the problem?

Comment: Ok, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variable is called `$capital`, then this should work:

```
print ((int)(1000*ceil($capital/1000000)));
```

It divides by 1000000, rounds up, then multiplies by 1000.